# ERROR rosout: Calibrate arm failed: Robust controller failed

Tags: control, ros, calibration, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to calibrate Baxter's arms to have an accurate control(get rid of the unnecessary drifts of  joints). On visual inspection I see that after running the script all the joints do get calibrated but suddenly at a very specific position every time(I believe that is just after calibrating W2), the arms disables itself with above error. I know the arm isn't calibrated properly because when I hold the cuff off button (zero gravity mode) the arm pulls back itself (a sign of poorly calibrate arm).
Same thing happens when I reboot Baxter and run the Tare example.
Any suggestion what I should do?

Also does having a torque control over any position/ velocity control or torque control alone help in avoid the drifting of arm. The reason I ask this is I when I command the arm to move to a position (I use IKsolver) it tries to reach there but the motion is not precise. It drifts off from the actual position and recovers after a sec or two to the original position. Maybe with torque control I can have a more accurate movement. I might be wrong.
Any help much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230250/error-rosout:-calibrate-arm-failed:-robust-controller-failed/) by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Minute leveling adjustment and running the calibration and tare example a couple of time worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) with karma: 51 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-16**:
Have you contacted Rethink about this? Seems like a question for their support department.